# JAXB unmarshaller's handleEvent not being called

Tags: java, json, jaxb, jersey

I'm trying to setup a simple Jersey JAX-RS application using MOXy for JAXB JSON support and I wanted to customise the unmarshaller. I did the following:

```
@Provider
public class CustomProvider extends ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider{
  @Override
  protected void preReadFrom(..., Unmarshaller unmarshaller) throws JAXBException{
    super.preReadFrom(...);
    System.out.println("preReadFrom entered");

    unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler(){
      @Override
      public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event){
        System.out.println("Entered handleEvent");

        return false;
      }
    });
  }
}
```

I wrote an override for `preReadFrom` and set an event handler on the unmarshaller. When I pass an invalid JSON body, print statement in `preReadFrom` executes but not the one in event handler. So the provider is registered properly but the event handler is not being called.

What might cause this issue?

What I want to achieve is when a user passes extraneous attributes in the JSON body, I want to throw an error (By default, these attributes are ignored). Searching on various websites, adding an event handler is the only way to do that. It would be great if I can achieve this in a different way too.

Comment: Why not just customize the `Unmarshaller` that is passed to `preReadFrom` before it gets passed? Why do you need a whole new provider? Could you also provide some code that is runnable to test with?

Comment: I am doing that. I'm customizing the unmarshaller passed to `preReadFrom`. By customizing, if you mean setting some properties - I added my intent to the question. I couldn't find any attribute that achieves that intent.

Comment: Can you not access the `Unmarshaller` *before* it gets passed to the `preReadFrom` method? Where does it come from?

Comment: Any particular reason why that would be beneficial? Also can we do that?

Comment: Well then you can change the `Unmarshaller` directly, instead of having to make a new provider. Where is `preReadFrom` called?

Comment: I register this provider with moxy and at runtime, to unmarshall  a JSON, it calls unmarshall in this class (this method is present in ConfigurableMOXyJsonProvider) which creates an unmarshaller and calls preReadFrom before doing the actual unmarhsall work.

Comment: Okay, I see now, yea nvm you can't access it before.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/158445/discussion-between-river-and-nitishch).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I assume `System.out.println("preReadFrom entered");` is getting called, and your `CustomProvider` is *actually* registered and used. Because in Weblogic e.g even if you register a different provider, still default `ConfigurableMoxyJsonProvider` is getting called unless you disable Moxy.
2. If first assumption is correct, then for sure you will be getting `public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event)` called for validations like if your Pojo, attribute is of numeric and you are passing String in json.
3. For `UnmappedElements`, I have seen that Moxy, "ignores" the warning for Json. What that means is if your pojo is like below:

   ```
   public class Emp {
       public Emp() {
           super();
       }
       private int id ;
       public void setId(int id) {
           this.id = id;
       }

       public int getId() {
           return id;
       }

   }
   ```

   And your Json is like: `{"id" : 11, "name1" : 111}` then your `handleEvent` won't be called. Reason being the Moxy uses [org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.record.UnmarshalRecordI‌mpl.startUnmappedEle‌​ment()](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.eclipse.persistence/eclipselink/2.5.0/org/eclipse/persistence/internal/oxm/record/UnmarshalRecordImpl.java#UnmarshalRecordImpl.startUnmappedElement%28java.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Cjava.lang.String%2Corg.xml.sax.Attributes%29) that has a check to see if the media type is xml prior to issuing a warning to the event handler.

So how to solve it for throw. I may not know the best of answer but here is my solution :

In your `preReadFrom` method add your custom  `UnmappedHandlerClass` like below

```
protected void preReadFrom(Class<Object> type, Type genericType, Annotation[] annotations, MediaType mediaType,
                           MultivaluedMap<String, String> httpHeaders,
                           Unmarshaller unmarshaller) throws JAXBException {
    System.out.println("preReadFrom entered");
    super.preReadFrom(type, genericType, annotations, MediaType.WILDCARD_TYPE, httpHeaders, unmarshaller);
    System.out.println("preReadFrom returned from super");

    //new code
    if(unmarshaller instanceof org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller) {
        org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller   moxyUn = ( org.eclipse.persistence.jaxb.JAXBUnmarshaller)unmarshaller;
        moxyUn.getXMLUnmarshaller().setUnmappedContentHandlerClass(CustomUnmapped.class);
    }
//your existing code
    unmarshaller.setEventHandler(new ValidationEventHandler() {
        @Override
        public boolean handleEvent(ValidationEvent event) {
            System.out.println("Entered handleEvent");

            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

And you can use Customunmapped class like this:

```
class CustomUnmapped extends org.eclipse.persistence.internal.oxm.unmapped.DefaultUnmappedContentHandler {
    @Override
    public void startElement(String p1, String p2, String p3, Attributes p4) throws SAXException {
        throw new SAXNotRecognizedException(p1);
    }
}
```

That shall work. But before trying 3, just make sure that your a) CustomProvider is actually being called by adding a breakpoint, or System.out.. statement. and b) Your handleEvent is called for generic errors like passing a string x in json, for number field.

Comment: After having said so, I would also like to check with @blaise-doughan of Moxy team, to find out on Unmapped Json fields and if there is an easier way to handle that.

Comment: @nitishc `What I want to achieve is when a user passes extraneous attributes in the JSON body, I want to throw an error ` This line suggest you indeed need Custom UnmappedContentHandler along with ValidationHandler.

Comment: Wow! Thanks for elaboration in point 2. Till now I was checking by passing an invalid JSON. In such cases the handleEvent is not called. But when I passed a string instead of a number - as you said - it is called! I wonder why.

Comment: That is explained in point 3 @nitishch  Reason is the the default "Unampped" element handling works only for xml, because of a check in class mentioned in point 3 above. And that can be solved using the snippet i added.

Comment: Thanks. This works. It reports error for any unmapped element in the root class. But I have nested classes. So The root element A will have a List<B> list_of_Bs. The problem is that for every valid attribute in B, the CustomUnmapped's startElement is called.

Comment: Let me check that and get back to you on this. Are you saying if you have json like : `{"A": {"id": "something","B": [{"idofb": "value1","attribute1": "value1"}, {"idofb": "id2","attribute1": "value2"}]}}` and your child pojo B has idofb and attribute1 as valid property, but still calls are going to CustomUnmapped startElement for them?

Comment: Exactly. That's the case.

Comment: It turns out that's because of some wrong configuration in a ContextResolver. I had `JAXBContext.property(ServerProperties.MOXY_JSON_FEATURE_DISABLE, true)` in the ContextResolver. For some reason, I removed it and everything is working fine now :)